# When testing REST api i get a 200OK when i should get 403

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-test

I'm writing some tests for my rest API and this is the controller I'm using this post:

```
@PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> add(@RequestBody @Valid Product product) {
        List<Product> recentProduct = productService.findAllRecent();
        for(Product p : recentProduct){
            if(p.getName().equals(product.getName()) && p.getId() == product.getId()){
                return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
            }
        }
            productService.add(product);
            return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

This is my test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc   
public class ProductControllerTest {
   @Autowired
   private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;
   @MockBean
   private ProductRepository productRepository;
   @Autowired
   private MockMvc mockMvc;
   @Autowired
   ProductController productController;
   @Autowired
   ProductService productService;

   @Test
   void testAddOnceShouldReturn201() {

       Product product = new Product(1, "TestSameName", LocalDateTime.now());
       
       productController.add(product);
       Assertions.assertTrue(productController.add(product).getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful());
   }

   @Test
   void testAddTwiceRecentShouldReturn403() {
       Product product = new Product(1, "TestName", LocalDateTime.now());
       Product product2 = new Product(1, "TestName", LocalDateTime.now());
       productController.add(product);
       ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity("/v1/products", product,String.class);
       productController.add(product2);
       ResponseEntity<String> response2 = restTemplate.postForEntity("/v1/products", product2,String.class);
       Assertions.assertTrue(response2.getStatusCode().is4xxClientError());
   }
...
```

So my findAllRecent fetches recently added data to my database. I than create a list and i check against it to see if the new addition is found there, I think the problem resides in that part, for some reason my list might be coming empty or something, i add two equal products even id because I don't have any restraints on that.
So I'm getting a 200ok when i should be getting a 403.

Any tips and help is apreciated. Thanks in advance.

[Edit] I should add if i post the requests manually on postman or through curl i get the desired behavior. Added entire Test class as requested.

[Edit 157] I'm using H2 as a database.I'm not sure if that would matter since I'm adding both products at the same time and both should be in memory.

Comment: There's a lot of things missing. What does your entire test class look like? Where is response getting set?

Comment: @George my bad i must've deleted because i had some system outs in there removed it so it would be cleaner. Also added the "entire" class as requested, not the imports tho.

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but a [403](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) is inappropriate here. That indicates the user is not authorized to view the data, and has to do with user authentication. What you probably want is `400` (Bad request).

Comment: Yeah i would use 400 but that's the requirements, honestly is for a job interview. I'm wondering if the add is being saved on the database because if it isn't my list would come empty and I'd not fall in the if statement or the for loop for that matter.

Comment: you are mocking `ProductRepository` but there is no mocking setup. Also there is no code for `ProductService`. How are we supposed to help if the codebase is not shown